# Boost bimap fails to compile with gcc 10, c++20. Looking for temporary fix

Tags: c++, boost, c++20, gcc10

With gcc 10.1 and boost 1.73.0, the following code

```
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>

int main() {
  boost::bimap<int, int> lookup;
}
```

fails to compile with flags `-O2 --std=c++20`, but will succeed with flags `-O2 -std=c++17` (verified with compiler explorer).

This is possibly related to the following issue: https://github.com/boostorg/bimap/pull/15 (deprecated `std::allocator<void>`)

Is there some workaround I can use for now to get this code to successfully compile with `--std=c++20`?

Comment: Why don't you use standard [C++ containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) e.g. two coupled `std::map<int,int>` or `std::unordered_map<int,int>` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason behind the error is not that the `std::allocator<void>` specialization is *removed*. Actually, it's still valid as the primary template with the `void` argument. The code fails to compile, because `::rebind` is no longer part of `std::allocator` itself. Instead, an implementation should use  `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::rebind_alloc<U>`.

Fortunately, most containers usually allow to specify a custom allocator as a template argument. It's also the case for `boost::bimap`, where an allocator can be the third, fourth or fifth template parameter, according to [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/the_tutorial/complete_instantiation_scheme.html). It defaults to `std::allocator`, but instead, `boost::container::allocator` can be used, which does not produce the error:

```
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
#include <boost/container/allocator.hpp>

int main() {
  boost::bimap<int, int, boost::container::allocator<int>> lookup;
}
```

---

This [issue](https://github.com/boostorg/bimap/issues/23) has recently been fixed in [6fba6e5](https://github.com/boostorg/bimap/commit/6fba6e5de3a5d9b0675a875fdac8aad9238d6dd8). `boost::bimap` now properly detects if a nested `::rebind` is available:

```
template<class A, class T, class = void>
struct allocator_rebind {
    typedef typename detail::alloc_to<A, T>::type type;
};

template<class A, class T>
struct allocator_rebind<A, T,
    typename detail::alloc_void<typename A::template rebind<T>::other>::type> {
    typedef typename A::template rebind<T>::other type;
};
```